# SQL Server : String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting a subset of data from one table into another and am getting a "string or binary data would be truncated" error. I am inserting by using a SELECT statement to take a subset of data from the source table and INSERT it into the destination table. I have identified the column which is causing the issue. HOWEVER, the subset of data within the source column in question is NOT larger than the data type of the destination table.

The column causing the issue has the following properties:
The source table column has a varchar(25) data type;
The destination table column has a varchar(10) data type;
The subset of data being taken from the source table column does not exceed 10 bytes;
The source table column does have data which is more than 10 bytes long; at most 14 bytes. However, it is filtered out in the SELECT statement.

Modifying the destination column to match the source column corrects the issue which makes sense. However inserted data into the destination column still does not exceed 10 bytes. 
Using SET ANSI_WARNINGS on ignores the error and INSERT the records. However if you compare to the original SELECT statement, no data has actually been lost!

```
--example script
create table #temptest
(
  assessteamID varchar(10) null
)
insert into #tempTest

--assessTeamID returned from this query at most 10 bytes in length
Select  rt.assessteamID
from    ipm_info_reporting_dest.dbo.t_PledgeRTT rt
    left join ipm_info_reporting_dest.dbo.iPM_Referrals r on    rt.firstrefrlrefno = r.refrl_refno
    left join ipm_info_reporting_dest.dbo.iPM_ResourceLookup rl on rt.epstartteamid = rl.ipmcode
    LEFT JOIN ipm_info_reporting_dest.[dbo].[iPM_Patients] pat ON rt.facility_id =pat.facility_id 
    left join Static_Reporting_Lorenzo.dbo.static_iPM_ResourceLookup rl2 on rt.assessteamID = rl2.ipmcode
where   assessdate >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -4,  Getdate())), 0)
    AND assessdate <= GETDATE()
    AND r.priorityid = 'E'
    AND ISNULL(rl2.[TeamFunctionID],'')  NOT IN ('LIAISON', 'MS');
```

Even though the source and destination columns data types do not match since the SELECT statement filters down the data to values which are legal I would expect this to work. I am pretty sure this has always worked before today.
Is anyone aware of any scenarios or SQL Server settings which could cause this? I can fix the issue by making the destination column larger. However I am particularly interested in why this could occur.

Comment: *"assessTeamID returned from this query at **most 10 bytes in length**"* 10 bytes <>  10 characters (although it does that for `varchar`, but i doubt that's the data type for `assessteamID`). For example a `bigint` is only 8 bytes and have up to 29 characters (`-9223372036854775808`). For an `nvarchar` each character is 2 bytes in size, so `N'abc'` would be 6 bytes in size. A `uniqueidentifier` is 16 bytes in size, but 36 characters long. You could easily have a value that is less than 10 bytes in size, but larger than 10 characters; and that seems to be what the problem is here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is definatley not what the problem is as the data type is varchar.

Comment: Then you'll need to supply Sample Data that we can use replicate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding a simple `LEN(rt.assessteamID) > 10` check to the `WHERE` to *really* verify your filtering logic is doing what you think it does? Also, does `LEFT(rt.assessteamID, 10)` actually remove the error? Last but not least, does adding `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` change anything? (The optimizer often uses more conservative/"obvious" plans if forced to stick to serial processing.)

Comment: Adding len(rt.assessteamID) > 10 returns no rows so the filtering logic is fine. Adding Left(rt.assessTeamID, 10) DOES remove the error. Adding a filter of LEN(rt.assessteamID) < 11 also removes the error. However in both cases the dataset is the same as the original, the only difference being the INSERT works. For example the record number when(rt.assessTeamID) < 11 is applied and is not applied is the same. However when it is not applied the INSERT fails and when it is applied it doesn't.

Comment: Then it sounds like the optimizer is shunting the check for the string length to the "wrong" place depending on the execution plan of the query; you might check that by comparing plans for the various different approaches. In general, in T-SQL an expression must be valid regardless of whether conditions should "logically" filter out errors; this is why things like `1 / x` can give an error even if the query is structured in such a way that all rows with `x = 0` are filtered out. This is a source of many bug reports, which are usually closed as "working as designed for performance purposes".

Comment: SQL Server doesn't know before you run the query if the results will include the invalid rows. Whether or not those rows are included in the result set is not relevant as SQL can't make this determination before executing the query. It's just how SQL works and you can't really do anything to change it except defensively code around the problem.